# If $f'(x) = -f(x)$ and $f(1)=1$, then what is $f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

If $f'(x) = -f(x)$ and $f(1)=1$, then $f(x)=$

(a) $1/2e^{-2x+2}$

(b) $e^{-x-1}$

(c) $e^{1-x}$

(d) $e^{-x}$

(e) $-e^{x}$

If you plug in $1$ for $x$ in option c it gives you $e^{1-1}$ or $e^0$ which is $1$ hence what is needed.

Comment: If you write your work here demonstrating why you think it is b, then we will read over it and check. I encourage you to [edit] in your work.

Comment: Before you commit yourself, make sure you compute $f(1)$.

Comment: Yes, the silly people who wrote the question should have made it harder for you.

Comment: It would also be good to show that no other option satisfies the conditions. Multiple choice questions aren't always of the form: Which **one** option is true?

Comment: How to turn an ODE question into a precalc question...

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** All you need to do in this case is to evaluate $f(1)$: $f_A(1), f_B(1), f_C(1), f_D(1), f_E(1)$.
Show your calculations in each case.

Doing that rules out all possibilities except $(C)$, irregardless of the first condition, though you want to evaluate $f'_C(x)$ to show that $f_C = f'_C$.

Comment: Yeah, but that's because it's a really poorly-constructed question. They should have at least three answers with $f(1)=1$.

Comment: Thank you guys very much, this was very helpful.

Comment: You're welcome, Sergio!

Comment: @amWhy Only b) c) d) satisfy the ODE, actually. But luckily c) is the one.

Comment: You're right, julien! ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: looks like a good hint to me +1

Answer (score 1):

If $f'(x) = -f(x)$,
then
$0 = f'(x)+f(x)
= e^x(f'(x)+f(x))
= (e^x f(x))'
$
so $e^x f(x)$ is constant.

Set $e^x f(x) = c$
and set $x = 1$.
Then, since $f(1) = 1$,
$c = e f(1) = e$
so $f(x) = e e^{-x} = e^{1-x}$.

An alternative solution is to write
$f'(x)/f(x) = -1$
so $(\ln(f(x))'=-1$
so $\ln f(x) = c-x$
or $f(x) = e^{c-x}$
for some constant $c$.

This has the problem that $f(x) = 0$ causes problems,
and the first solution does not have this problem.

Comment: sir, why we need $f(x)=0$, In the case of exponential functions in generally we never get $f(x)=0$

Comment: At the start of the problem, we do $not$ know that $f(x) = 0$ never occurs. Only at the end do we know this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a separable differential equation.  We have $\frac{dy}{dx} = -y$, so

$$\int \frac{dy}{y} = \int -dx$$

and we get get the general solution $y = e^{-x + k}$.  The initial condition $y(1) = 1$ implies $k = 1$ in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If $f'(x) = -f(x)$,
then

$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=-1 \implies \int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx=-\int dx \implies f(x)= e^{-(x-k)}\ $ (Here k is the integration constant)

so $e^x f(x)$ is constant.

Here, $e^x f(x) = e^k$
and set $x = 1$.
Then, since $f(1) = 1$,
$e f(1) =e^k $
so $f(x) = e e^{-x} = e^{1-x}$.

so, $f(x)= e^{1-x} \implies\ \ $ Option (b) is correct.

Comment: What happens if $f(x) = 0$ at some $x$?